# iOS UINavigationBar shift view down

Tags: ios, resize, uinavigationbar

I have a view that is used in a UINavigationController and and is automatically pushed down to fit the window as expected. However I need to present the same view as a Model and it does not have a UINavigationController (or need one) so I just add a UINavigationBar like so:

```
if (presentedAsModal == YES) {
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];

    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)];

    UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
    item.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
    item.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:180/255.0f blue:220/255.0f alpha:1.f]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:140/255.0f blue:180/255.0f alpha:1.f]];
    }
```

However, the navigationBar does not automatically push down the VC and it ends up covering up part of my View. is there a way to make the VC resize to fit the new available space once the navigationBar is added (I don't want to do it manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could embed the vc inside a navigation controller for modal presentation or do a little trick modifying the bounds origin:

```
CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
bounds.origin.y = -44;
self.bounds = bounds;
...
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 44)];
...
```

Comment: That works, I wish there was a clean property I could access to accomplish this but I guess not? I knew I could put it in a NavController however it seemed wrong considering I did not need the NavController just the bar for looks/back button.

Comment: The navigation controller makes your view smaller before adding it to its view so there is no "navigation bar shrinking behavior". A navigation bar is a view/control like everything else